# Can not using websocket with nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, websocket, activemq

I am using `Activemq` as broker, client side is `Paho js` to send websocket request(ws protocol).
Everything work fine on server, but when the server start to set nginx as proxy, the client can not connect to server( but I can connect to Activemq UI web). My nginx setting is:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
     default upgrade;
     '' close;
}
server {
     listen 16614;
     server_name mq.mysite.com;
     access_log /var/log/docker/nginx/access_activemq.log activemq_custom;

     location / {
           proxy_pass  http://192.168.10.13:16614; 
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

     }
}
```

I am using 80 port to listen ActiveMQ webUI, and 16614 to ws protocol.

Is there any missing step?

Comment: Oh, so strange, it works after restart Nginx docker container. `nginx -s reload` does not work.

Comment: Write this in your own answer not in a comment. Describe what the cause of problem was and how you resolved it. After 48 hours you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from Docker, `nginx -s reload` command sometimes does not work exactle, I have to restart Nginx container.